# We are using direction API in which, while searching we are not getting the all locations in the suggestion box of all the islands used in the style

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-api-directions

We are using direction API in which, while searching we are not getting the all locations in the suggestion box of all the islands used in the style.
In Map box map searching suggestions we are not getting all the places in the suggestion box.
is there any way to add places in database of map box ?
what can we do for adding locations into it?